# Randomwalk not Walkking JAVA

Tags: java

I am creating a program that simulates the colonoe ants for a start I want to create a small point that matches in randomwalk, my prebléme is that the point does not move from its initial position I understand as or is the error yet there is no error message that appears

```
   public class Ant extends JFrame
{
    static int x = 20;
    static int y = 60;
    int rad = 15; 
    Ant()
    {
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(500, 500);  
        setResizable(false);
    }

    public void move(int x , int y)
    {

        double randomDouble = Math.random();
        randomDouble = randomDouble * 4 + 1;
        int randomInt = (int) randomDouble;
        switch(randomInt) {

        case 1 : 
            x+=1;
        case 2 : 
            x-=1;
        case 3 : 
            y+=1;
        case 4 : 
            y-=1;

        } 

            repaint();


    }



    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paint(g);
        g.fillOval(x, y, rad, rad);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
         Ant a = new Ant();

         while(true)
          {
              a.move(x,y);
              a.repaint();
              try {
                  Thread.sleep(100);
              }catch(Exception e)
              {

              }       
          }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `move` method doesn't change the **class variables (static variables)** but **local variables**.
A simple way is to modify your code by following steps:

Step 1: Remove local variables from `move` method such as:

```
public void move() {
   ...
}
```

Step 2: Call it without passing any variables:

```
a.move();
```